# How to align items on the left side in column when using react bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using React bootstrap and using Row and Col components of it. Column is aligning image horizontally centre by default. How to move this image to the left in the column?

Code

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";

function Header() {
  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Image src="https://github.com/gautam-in/shopping-cart-assignment/blob/master/static/images/logo.png?raw=true" />
        </Col>
        <Col>Second</Col>
        <Col>Third</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have other CSS or is there an outer-component. By default the image is not centered: https://codeply.com/p/fEc8Uzm1av

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure of how bootstrap's css tricks work BUT you can always use inline styling on the Col element as a hack lol.. Like so:

```
<Container fluid>
  <Row style>
    <Col style={{disply:'flex', justifyContent:'left'}}>
      <Image src="https://github.com/gautam-in/shopping-cart-assignment/blob/master/static/images/logo.png?raw=true"/>
    </Col>
    <Col>Second</Col>
    <Col>Third</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

that should do it!

Comment: One typo above; replace `disply` with `display`.

Answer (score 0):

React bootstrap provides a flexible grid system that you can align as you wish. The react-bootstrap has a class called "no-gutters" which is used to remove the negative margins from the row class and the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns. You can have a look here [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).

About your code, I think you should add this:

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";

    function Header() {
      return (
        <Container fluid>
         <div class="row no-gutters">
          <Row>
            <Col "col-12 col-sm-6 you can play with it and see which one works">
              <Image src="https://github.com/gautam-in/shopping-cart-assignment/blob/master/static/images/logo.png?raw=true" />
            </Col>
            <Col>Second</Col>
            <Col>Third</Col>
          </Row>
         </div>
        </Container>
      );
    }
```